# ¿Cual es el origen de la expresión "estar en edad de merecer"?

Tags: historia, locuciones

En el DLE se puede ver la definición de la frase:

> [**edad de merecer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EN8xffh)
>
> 1. f. Época en que los jóvenes buscan mujer o marido.

Dejando de lado que la frase me parece un poco cómica, ¿cuál es su origen? ¿Qué se "merece" alguien a determinada edad? ¿El amor? ¿Las dotes que se regalaban en el pasado para casarse?

Comment: Siempre pensé que se refería a merecer una esposa o un marido. En un par de sitios he leído que se refería a las mujeres solo y lo que se merecía era la distinción de señora, en este blog: http://clasico.aurora-israel.co.il/blogs/israel/oportunidades/2419.html y este libro: https://books.google.es/books?id=T6clDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT110&dq=edad+de+merecer&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3ifKLx5vYAhXkKsAKHYdJCOgQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=edad%20de%20merecer&f=false. Pero no hay fuentes ni nada, así que no me queda nada claro

Comment: sera censura de la palabra procrear?

Comment: @Mike me suena bastante

Comment: Siempre he entendido que se aplica solo a mujeres, y que lo que se "merece" es pasar a ser **señora casada**, distinguida de una niña, llevando el apellido de un marido

Comment: A lo mejor porqué hubo un tiempo cuando las únicas mujeres que ganaban dinero eran las meretrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sospecho que el significado de la palabra *merecer* se acercó en el pasado, por razones teológicas, a nuestros conceptos de "conciencia" y "juicio". Estuve mirando algunos textos del siglo XVII, en los que no queda tan claro a qué se refiere *merecer*, aunque lo más probable es que hablen de "hacer mérito para alcanzar el cielo o perderse en el pecado". Etimológicamente, el verbo latino clásico era *merere*, que significaba "ganar, alcanzar", del cual derivó el latín vulgar *merescere*: "ser digno".

El siguiente es un fragmento de [*Hero y Leandro*](https://books.google.cl/books?id=fctPFXKpiXAC&lpg=PA118&ots=JgK1rm9Y9N&dq=boscan%20merecer%20junto%20al%20pecar&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q=el%20merecer%20tan%20junto%20al%20pecar%20vino&f=false), de Juan Boscán (1543).

> (...)
>   de Hero la mano se atrevió a tomalla.
>  
>   Mas esto fue con un ardor tamaño,
>  
>   de una congoja tal, tan entrañable,
>  
>   con un gemir tan bajo y tan profundo,
>  
>   de su necesidad tan gran testigo,
>  
>   que desculpó la culpa del pecado.
>  
>   **Y el merecer tan junto al pecar vino**,
>  
>   que no sé cuál fue más ni cuál primero.

Me es difícil interpretar el verso marcado, pero al leer el resto del poema se descubre que el conflicto de Hero es entre el amor romántico (el *pecar*) y la honestidad cristiana (el *merecer*).

El siguiente fragmento es un poco más claro. Se trata de un manual para eclesiásticos: [Summa de casos de consciencia](https://books.google.cl/books?id=n7p7fmFwIagC&dq=edad%20para%20merecer%20y%20peccar&pg=PA38-IA1#v=onepage&q=edad%20para%20merecer%20y%20peccar&f=false), de Juan Pedraza (1579).

> Sexto: Si no se confesó cuando era obligado. En siendo uno de edad que tenga discreción: que es saber qué cosa es pecar, es obligado a confesarse una vez en el año. (...) cuando se ofrece peligro de muerte, como tormenta o batalla, y la mujer que tiene ya sabido que su parto es dificultoso (...) será obligado a confesarse luego antemano. En esto hay gran descuido en muchos, que con decir niño es, inocente, dejan morir sin confesión sus hijos de siete o ocho años, **siendo comunmente esta edad para merecer y pecar**.

Se puede observar en esta última frase un claro indicio de la "edad de merecer", aunque no me queda claro a qué se refiere exactamente con *merecer*, si a "tener discernimiento" ("discreción") o directamente a "ser digno de un castigo".

Por último otro libro prescriptivo: un fragmento del [Orden de bien casar, y avisos de casados](https://books.google.cl/books?id=tohXAAAAcAAJ&dq=juyzio%20para%20peccar%20merecer&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q=juyzio%20para%20peccar%20merecer&f=false), del cura Juan Esteban, de 1595. Aquí nuevamente se vislumbra nuestra "edad de merecer".

> El tercer impedimento que impide el matrimonio es el voto simple de Castidad, o Religión. Ya es dicho, y te he enseñado, que es voto solemne, y que es voto simple. Que el voto solemne, es, el que se hace por alguna religión aprobada. Y el simple, el que cada uno hace por sí. Pues llegando un hombre a **aquella edad que tenga juicio para pecar o merecer**: puede regularmente hacer cualesquier votos y obligarse por ellos: dije regularmente porque el voto solemnde de Castidad, o Religión, no puede hasta la edad que queda dicho.

Si la palabra *merecer* significó alguna vez (como parece demostrarse en los ejemplos anteriores) "juicio" o "capacidad de discernimiento entre lo que está bien y lo que es pecado", entonces no habría problemas en decir que la *edad para merecer* es, en palabras modernas, la edad en la que se alcanza la madurez. Sólo habría cambiado la preposición (ahora es ***de** merecer*), y el rango de años en los que se considera que la persona es moralmente madura.

Por último agrego una curiosidad etimológica off topic a propósito del significado "ganar" que tenía la palabra latina *merere*, de la que deriva *merecer*. La palabra *meretrix* originalmente significó, según Corominas, "la mujer que se gana la vida por sí misma". Por obvias razones sociales, en Roma esto comenzó a significar "la mujer que se casa por dinero", y ahora en español tenemos a la *meretriz*, o sea, la prostituta.

Comment: Ya había marcado otra como respuesta, pero el contexto que colocas es muy claro y tiene mucho sentido que alcanzar cierta madurez sea el significado de merecer. Además que se aplica sin distinción de género, por lo que se acerca mucho a la definición del DLE.

Comment: @MauricioMartinez que no te dé ningún reparo cambiar la respuesta aceptada si aparece una nueva que resuelve mejor tu duda. Esta respuesta me parece muy acertada y mucho más trabajada que la mía, así que apoyo tu decisión. :-)

Comment: La palabra `meretriz` la encuentras en varios idiomas incluso en ingles: `meretrix`. Y, por cierto, hay unas almejas también llamadas `meretrix`: [Meretrix lusoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meretrix_(bivalve))

Answer (score 4):

He buscado en el CORDE y en la hemeroteca de la BNE (el caso más antiguo es de principios del siglo XIX), pero no he encontrado nada que indique a qué se puede referir ese *merecer*.

Sin embargo, consultando el DLE vemos que hay una acepción de *merecer* que es intransitiva y que, por tanto, no se refiere a ningún objeto directo concreto:

> **[merecer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OzffqGN)**
>
> 4. intr. Hacer méritos, buenas obras, ser digno de premio.

Según esta acepción, la *edad de merecer* sería sencillamente la edad en la que tienes que empezar a hacerte valer por ti mismo sin depender de nadie. Es decir, la edad a la que tienes que empezar a hacer méritos y ser digno de premio (entiendo yo que se refiere en este caso a ser digno de reconocimiento).

Por supuesto, entre los premios también estaría el amor, dado que también tienes que hacerte valer para encontrar una pareja.

Answer (score 2):

*Esto debería ser más bien un comentario pero no va a caber ahí muy bien.*

Pasé un tiempo viviendo en una comunidad campesina (en México) de unas doce familias.  Las decisiones comunitarias importantes se tomaban a través de la discusión y el consenso, con la participación de los que se consideraban adultos.  Algunos de los adultos que participaban eran en términos objetivos muy, muy jóvenes, incluso de quince años en un caso.  Ofrezco este ejemplo porque me parece que nos podría dar una indicación del funcionamiento de las relaciones sociológicas que podrían haber dado origen a la expresión que te interesa.

En dicha comunidad, ¿cómo llegó el joven de quince años a ser considerado como adulto en su comunidad?  Es decir, ¿a merecer respeto?

En su caso particular, este individuo era el hijo mayor de una gran familia, que había quedado sin papá por factores complejos.  El individuo trabajaba como hombre al lado de los demás señores.  Tenía buena participación en las discusiones de la comunidad.  Se enamoró de una joven de la comunidad.  Construyó su propia casa (rústica).  La pareja emprendió una vida de casados, con el visto bueno de los papás de ella y la mamá de él.  El número de unidades familiares de la comunidad se aumentó por una.

*(Por si alguien se interesa en la suerte de la familia del joven: después de que el joven se fue a vivir con su pareja... la comunidad seguía dándoles la misma porción de maíz y frijol que tocaba a sus hermanos y mamá.  Se calculaba a base del número de miembros de la familia.)*